# Global Entry Status

Tags: global-entry

I have been approved for the Global Entry over a year ago but when entering US from my International trips every time I am receiving the red X and am taken to the additional screening by agents. After few minutes they let me go without any explanations. I am hesitant to use Global Entry now and next time will go thru the regular line. Is there any way to find out why???

Comment: Did you ask the Officer?

Comment: Yes, I did every time but received no real answer.

Comment: How many trips have you taken since you started using Global Entry, where, and when?  It isn't unusual to have additional screening when using GE/NEXUS/SENTRI, but it's a little unusual if it happens all the time.  I'd still continue using it in the hopes that things smooth out.  Agents know you have been background-checked so you do have a greater trust level applied to you when you use it.  (And regular agents will know you have it, too; it'll show on their screens.)

Comment: I made 4 trips in 2017 total since I got Global Entry: France, DR, Colombia and Poland. Every time red X and I was escorted to the "holding" area. I have 3 trips coming up to Poland, Brazil and Argentina so will keep using the Global Entry and hopefully they can provide more details. They are just not too chatty as to why I am being stopped for additional screening.. Thanks for your feedback Jim. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Daniel Could just be something weird about the airlines you're flying or how you're answering the questions.  I'd keep doing what you're doing and see what happens as you continue traveling.

Comment: All my flights were and will be on United so can't see this being a factor.